# No linked databased of the user is being created during registration - Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to make a user authentication with Firebase and at the same time store the user Full name and email address in the database linked with the User UID that is created during authentication. Here, my database table name is `Users` and I have been trying the following code to link my user information with its UID.

With the following code, the user gets registered but no associated database is being formed. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance for the suggestion.

```
public class SignUpActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    EditText editTextFullName, editTextEmail, editTextPassword;

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference ref;
    Users users;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);

        editTextFullName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextFullName);
        editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
        editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        ref = database.getReference("Users");
        users = new Users();
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        findViewById(R.id.buttonSignUp).setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private void getValues() {
        users.setFullName(editTextFullName.getText().toString());
        users.setEmail(editTextEmail.getText().toString());
    }

    private void registerUser() {
        final String fullname = editTextFullName.getText().toString().trim();
        String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();

        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    finish();
                    startActivity(new Intent(SignUpActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class));

                    final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            getValues();
                            ref.child(""+ user +"").setValue(users);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });

                } else {

                    if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You are already registered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.buttonSignUp:
                registerUser();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Something like this:
[image]

Comment: You are immediately calling finish inside onSuccess, so the code after that not getting executed

Comment: Comment finish() & make new instance of DatabaseReference  instead of using 'ref'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not forget the executor class,this is a proper example:

```
 auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(SignupActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "createUserWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                            // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                            // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "Authentication failed." + task.getException(),
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {
                                startActivity(new Intent(SignupActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                                finish();
                            }
                        }
                    });

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you are finishing the activity before it can write to database when you call

```
finish();
```

method

fire the intent once the data has been written to database i.e after

```
  ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        getValues();
                        ref.child(""+ user +"").setValue(users);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
startActivity(new Intent(SignUpActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class));
finish();
```

like this

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but still after the changes, it doesn't store the values in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need value event listener for that you can directly add to database like this :

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users");
databaseReference.push().setValue(users);
```

and you have to call `finish();` after the database call

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But sorry, here it says `getInstance` is not resolved. Could you please update the full method?

Comment: @Ashonko ohh i did spelling mistake but syntax is same as you can see on also https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#get_a_databasereference

Comment: Thanks for the update but it still doesn't store anything in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Start Activity and call finish() after setting the value to Database as @Rohit has suggested.

One more suggestion is; if you want to save data using UID, you will have to set it in the reference path like below:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users");

FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser(); 
if (user != null) {
    String UID = user.getUid(); //get UID of currently logged in user(new user in your case)

    ref.child(UID).setValue(users); //this will give you expected structure
    startActivity(new Intent(SignUpActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class));
    finish();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But sorry, here it says `getInstance` and `UID` are not resolved. Could you please update the full method?

Comment: Thank you for the update. But it still doesn't add anything to the database.